# Shiny - Error in ..stacktraceon..: could not find function "shioptions"

Tags: r, shiny

I have never seen this error before running a Shiny app and can't find anything about it after Googling. I've tried re-installing the `shiny` package and restarting R but nothing resolves it. Any insight?

Error after running `runApp()` from the local directory:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6093
Warning: Error in ..stacktraceon..: could not find function "shioptions"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error in ..stacktraceon..({ : could not find function "shioptions"
```

Traceback below:

```
5: Sys.sleep(0.001)
4: withCallingHandlers(expr, error = function(e) {
       if (is.null(attr(e, "stack.trace", exact = TRUE))) {
           calls <- sys.calls()
           attr(e, "stack.trace") <- calls
           stop(e)
       }
   })
3: captureStackTraces(while (!.globals$stopped) {
       serviceApp()
       Sys.sleep(0.001)
   })
2: ..stacktraceoff..(captureStackTraces(while (!.globals$stopped) {
       serviceApp()
       Sys.sleep(0.001)
   }))
1: runApp()
```

Comment: It might help if you posted some of your code in the future to see about local replication.

Answer (score 1):

Check the library("shiny") output from your R Console. I think you do not have the package loaded and/or you had an intentional upgrade.